Is this enough support at the base for a window bench?
I mismeasured when I was building this wood frame to support my window bench. Is this enough support for the backside, or do I need to redo my frame to cover more of the cabinet bottom? It’s about 1/2” on the back wood frame. These are IKEA Sektion cabinets.
I can’t move it back more because I need enough space in front for the toe kick.
We don’t plan on sitting on these often, and we just have kids mainly playing on these and < 175 lb adults sitting maybe 1 at a time.


what are we looking at in the picture? ... is the picture sideways?

A picture of a wider view of the whole area might help us pin down the existing picture more.

window bench? cabinets?   I'm lost here.  Please be more specific about your situation and provide a picture that allows those of us that are not there to understand it.

Looks like a 2x4 frame sitting on top of a hardwood floor, with a bench or cabinet on the left?

Sliding another piece of wood at the back will remove any worry about it moving/having enough support.

Sorry I was trying to figure out how to add multiple images to the post and forgot to add it: https://imgur.com/a/C464roK. The original photo is the top view - wall cabinet being used as a window bench on the left side. This photo shows more clearly (please ignore the other cabinet on the right going to redo that).

You want to follow the path of the weight transfer from the bench top to the floor, and that is where you need to provide support.
The back of the IKEA Sektion cabinets is cardboard or thin, compressed wood and is not structural. The side panels will carry the weight to the floor. So, the weight transfer will be from the benchtop to the side panels down to the base support to the floor.
You need to ensure the entire length of the side panels is supported. This would be a 2x4s perpendicular to the ones in your photo wherever the side panels are.


Got it, so essentially wherever there are adjoining individual cabinets I need another perpendicular wood support? I have 3 cabinets side by side so like this? https://imgur.com/a/4gpwB7O

@getrichordiediying, yes, that looks right.
